# Dynamic let form as part of reify within a macro

Tags: macros, clojure, reify

Ok, let's try to get this straight: my final intent is to provide a macro as an API to users which will look like:

```
(defscript [a b]
  (println a))
```

The result has to be an instance of a `Script` protocol, which looks like:

```
(defprotocol Script
  (run [this model]))
```

The idea being that the first argument to `defscript` is a list of symbols that needs to be bound to correspondent keys in the `model`:

```
(.run (defscript [a b] (println a)) {:a 1}) ;; yields 1
```

I can't come up with any code that can effectively produce such effect, as I'm constantly hitting a wall when trying to use the `model` parameter, since at macro expansion time it's just a symbol:

```
(defmacro invoke-
  [params model body]
  (let [p (flatten (map (fn [x] [x (model (keyword x))]) params))]
    `(let [~@p]
       ~body)))

(defmacro defscript
  [params & body]
  `(reify Script
    (run [~'this ~'model]
      (invoke- ~params ~'model ~@body))))
```

`invoke-` works fine if called directly:

```
(invoke- [a] {:a 1} (println a)) ;; prints 1
```

but it doesn't work when used within `defscript` as `model` can't be expanded correctly:

```
(.run (defscript [a] (println a)) {:a 1}) ;; prints nil
```

How can I get past this point and glue the pieces together?

Comment: What you describe sounds vaguely like the features provided in `clojure.template`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that basically, your argument vector is a shortcut for a destructuring binding:

```
(defscript [a b] body)  -> (reify Script (run [this {:keys [a b]}] body))
```

That way, model is destructured at run time, as it should be.